# How to set Z Index for Mobile Responsive ? HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, z-index

Hello All below is the expected output what i want to achieve. I tried but lacking some where. Below is my code.
[image]

I am using Z index all seems ok but when seen in mobile the design is not up to the mark.

Below is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style> 
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: #EEE;
  height: 60vw;
  width: 80vw;
}
.wrapper div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25%;
  width: 20%;
}
.wrapper .one {
  top: 26px;
  left: 150px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px #00000026;
}
.wrapper .two {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -23% 0 0 -31%;
  height: 60%;
  width: 40%;
  background: red;
}
.wrapper .three {
  top: 620px;
    left: 450px;
    height: 6%;
    background: green;
}</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">
    <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_297x176.jpg" style="width: 100%">
  </div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three">Read More</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am not able to achieve the desired output in css

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details about what your actual question is. There are a lot of differences between the mock-up and your html + css.

Nevertheless I think you have a general problem with how you layout things.
For responsiveness you should generally avoid using fixed pixels + position absolute. This might work on one screen size but not on others.
Try to achieve your desired output with the appropriate tools like css grid/flex.

But for the sake of the question you can move `one` into `two`:

```
...
<div class="two">
    <div class="one">
        <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_297x176.jpg" style="width: 100%">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="three">Read More</div>
...
```

and adjust your style like this:

```
.wrapper .one {
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px #00000026;
  position: relative;
}
```

PS. You can get rid of the white border around the page with `body { margin: 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
   <style>
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        background: #EEE;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px 0px;
    }

    .wrapper div {

        height: 25%;
        width: 20%;
    }

    .wrapper .one {
        height: auto;
        left: -10px;
        top: -10px;
        background: blue;
        z-index: 1;
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px #00000026;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .wrapper .two {
        margin: 0px auto;
        min-height: 480px;
        /* max-width: 767px; */
        background: red;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 480px;
    }

    .wrapper .three {
        bottom: -10px;
        right: -10px;
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        background: green;
        position: absolute;

    }

   </style>
```

use this as html

```
   <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="two">
        <div class="one">
            <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_297x176.jpg" style="width: 100%">
        </div>
        <div class="three">Read More</div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

u can try like this

Comment: Sure let me try this out